# Hide empty columns in PerformancePoint Scorecard dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, column, performancepoint, dashboard-designer-2013

I have a scorecard with several empty columns which I want to hide dynamically.

[image]

In the illustration above, I want to hide three empty columns, viz. MidYear Income, MidYear % and MidYear Status. 
Help please. And thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post how the HTML is rendered?

Answer (score -1):

You can not dynamically remove the empty row however in dashboard designer you can configure that will remove the all empty rows or you can specify the value to be displayed in the empty rows.

Comment: The question was to hide empty columns and not empty rows. Thanks for the try though.

Comment: You can also choose from scorecard settings to hide empty columns.

Comment: Thanks Jay. But I could not figure it out where this option is. Could you please send me a screenshot of this option. Thanks.